# ASP.Net which model to use for simple dashboard visualization of xml / database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am going to start a very basic ASP project and I am quite confused which flavor of ASP to choose.
Looks like there are ASP.Net webpages, WebForms, ASP.Net web forms etc .

I have done C# and have not done ASP before.

I want to basically create a simple table like 2D dashboard that will pick up values from a database or xml process them and show values in the table cells and mark the red, green blue etc based on their significance etc.

Please advise ASP.Net should be easy and suitable for this ? I have visual studio 2012 on my mahcine. I can not see ASP.Net Web page project in the new project options.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET could be suitable for this, absolutely. But isn't something you'd learn in a day or two. So, if you're willing to spend some time on this, delve right in.
IMHO, ASP.NET MVC is most preferable for several reasons, but might be difficult to start of with.

What you want to achieve sounds like something that could be done with a ASP.NET MVC Web API, some html, css & javascript I reckon. And an XML file or a DB of course, whichever has your preference.

To start a *Web Application* , go to File > New Project in VS. Here you can also choose a MVC App.